# how can i solve " Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated" error

Tags: php, deprecated, eregi

i am using php 5.3.0 and i am use wamp server
function is like that

```
eregi("^[ \f\r\t\n]{0,}(SELECT){1}(.+)$",$this->ss_last_query)  
eregi("^[ \f\r\t\n]{0,}(UPDATE|INSERT|DELETE){1}(.+)$",$this->ss_last_query)
```

Comment: I think `\s` will match every character in your character class. Also `{0,}` is most commonly represented as `*` :)

Comment: Also, `{1}` is redundant

Answer (score 6):

Two options

1. Don't use the `ereg*` functions (use the [PCRE suite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) instead)
2. Disable `E_DEPRECATED` error reporting. See [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

The best option is #1 as the entire POSIX Extended suite will be removed in a future version.

I can't comprehend how people are still using this. It's been marked for removal for years. Not to mention the pre-deprecated "These functions are inferior!" warning that was up for even longer.

Comment: Some people still use `mysql_*` too. :)

Comment: `mysql_*` doesn't appear to have been deprecated.

Comment: @ceejayoz Whilst that's true, there are *much* better options available

Comment: Sure, but there's a big difference between that and using functions that've you've been warned for years that they're going away...

Comment: mysql_ is easy for the beginners (me when I first learned how to write a registration scripts) and it was consistent for the people who didn't have to release code or need for it to be secure/user proof (me until I started coding for cash).  I would be lying if I said I will never show a new php'er mysql_*, but I do make an effort to teach any people with programming experience to use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the `i` modifier, which specifies that you want a case insensitive match with your regex.

So you want:

`preg_match("/regexhere/i", $str);`

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

If you must use eregi, but...

```
preg_match("/^[ \f\r\t\n]{0,}(UPDATE|INSERT|DELETE){1}(.+)$/is", $this->ss_last_query)
```

should also work.